# Spring Data MongoDB v3.x

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

The documentation has details of migration from 2.x to 3.x https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3

However, i cannot find the 3.x maven dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb

The latest available is only 2.2.6.RELEASE

Is 3.x not available as of now?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Data Neumann Release is not GA yet. Please have a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Neumann) for more information on the planned timeline.

Release candidates and snapshot builds are available via [repo.spring.io](https://repo.spring.io/).

```xml
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>spring-milestones</id>
  <name>libs-milestone</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <snapshots />
  <id>spring-snapshots</id>
  <name>libs-snapshot</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```